# Handling multiple fling motion detectors on android

Tags: event-handling, android-tabhost, android, android-viewpager

Basically I have a custom `TabHost` that uses `dispatchTouchEvent` to capture flings and change tabs.

The problem is, now I have a tab with a `ViewPager` inside of it.

What happens is that the `TabHost` is capturing the fling from the `ViewPager` and changing the tab.

I tried to work around with a check of the `super.dispatchTouchEvent` has handled the touch event, but apparently, this super call ALWAYS returns true.

Here is the code I tried using in my `TabHost`:

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        if(!handled) // This is always true... why?
            return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return handled;
    }
```

Is there a workarround to make this work?

How can I detect that the ViewPager handled the event and not change the tab?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want the tabs to handle the fling if you swipe on the tabs at the top and the view pager to handle the fling if the user flings on the view pager?

Comment: The view pager is not gonna occupy all the screen. Basically yes, I want the `TabHost` to NOT handle it IF the `ViewPager` handled it... I could make an ugly control variable but I would like to make something more ideal.

Comment: I have had a go looking into this, I guess my only solution would be to override the touch listeners for all items on your page, and return false on them when you want to return false.  But I guess like you say, it would be easier / but hacky to just set a flag on the viewpager touch event. Sorry I cant help anymore.